# Need help to resize iframe as the size of screen changes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating an earth surrounded by circular graph. The earth is created by using an iframe. I have created a graph and put it inside a dive and managed to overlay the earth on it. It appears fine on desktop but when i open it on phone or tablet, the size of graph behind reduces with screen but the size of earth remains same.

Live URL: https://netzero.co.in/calculator/

**I want the earth to adapt screen size i.e make it always look inside the circle graph.**

Code:

```
<style> 
.main_content {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.earth2{
    border-radius:50%;
}
.overlay-effect {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:50%;
  clip-path: circle(160px at center);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.earth {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border-radius:50%;
  left: 50%;
  top:50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: circle(160px at center);
}
</style>

<div class="main_content">
    <div class="graph" id="canvas-holder" style="width:100%">
    <canvas id="chart-area" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </div>

<div class="earth">
    <iframe class="earth2" src="https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/gltf_embed/2393" width="400px" height="400px" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
</div>
<div style="opacity:0%;background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);" class="overlay-effect" id="red-overlay">
    hi
</div>
```

[image: Desktop preview]
[image: Mobile preview]

Comment: Your code looks fine but the scaling at https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/ isn't linear. So as long you are not owner of nasa.gov you can't fix it. sorry.

Comment: PS: cool project. consider hosting the earth yourself. it isn't the best practice to implement such assets from a third party if not absolutely necessary.